# Prevent the conversion to text

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

If i add an column to a table via

```
alter table test add column (name varchar(1024));
```

The MySQL-Client sais:

```
Converting from VARCHAR to TEXT
```

How can i prevent this Conversion? Any idea?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? Before 5.0.3 the max length for a varchar field is 255.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your client libraries?  Varchar used to have a limit of 255...